# How to convert normal for loop to parallel stream in java

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am trying to convert normal for loop iterating an ArrayList to a parallel one. I came across the concepts of parallelStream.forEach() and parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList()). But not clear how to convert. Below is the sample code for normal for loop :

```
public List<FinPlan> getFinPlanList() {
List<FinPlan> newList = new ArrayList<>();

// get list of string   
List<String> finPlanIdsList = finPlanSearchRequest.getFinPlanIds();

// iterate list and add element to new list
    for(String planId: finPlanIdsList) {
    
        newList.add(retrieveFinPlan(planId));
    }
    
    return newList;
}
```

I tried with the following code but its giving me error that ""newList should be final".

```
    finPlanIdsList.parallelStream().forEach( planId -> {
            newList.add(retrieveFinPlan(planId));
    });
```

So, the main question is how to convert the above normal loop to  parallelStream.forEach() and parallelStream().collect() ?

Comment: What does not suit you new ArrayList<>(finPlanIdsList) ?

Comment: @АндрейКолычев - You will notice that the code is transforming from a list of strings to a list of `FinPlan` objects.

Comment: elements from list of string are used as parameter to call retrieveFinPlan(planId), which returns the required FinPlan object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compilation error in your current version is happening because a lambda expression is not allowed to make use of a local variable that is not either `final` or effectively final at the point that the lambda is created.

You could try fix it like this:

```
final List<FinPlan> = new ArrayList<>();

...

finPlanIdsList.parallelStream().forEach( planId -> {
        newList.add(retrieveFinPlan(planId));
});
```

... but that has the more subtle flaw that the code won't be thread-safe.  The `newList` object is potentially going to be updated from different threads ... and `ArrayList` is not a thread-safe class.

A correct solution is this:

```
List<FinPlan> newList = 
    finPlanIdsList.parallelStream()
                  .map(planId -> retrieveFinPlan(planId))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If it is essential that the result is an `ArrayList`, you can replace the `Collectors.toList()` expression with `Collections.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

In general, it is a bad idea for a stream to rely on side-effects.  In some cases you will get away with it.  In others ... no.

Answer (score 1):

Your method definitions appears to be incorrect as the getFinPlanList returns a FinPlan and not a List

Furthermore you can't use a local variable in your lambda expression that is not effectively final. Therefore it won't compile.
You can try using the following command for generating the list. Note that the order in which the objects are processed is not guaranteed once you apply parallelstream.

```
return finPlanIdsList.parallelStream().map(finPlanId->retrieveFinPlan(finPlanId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is not the original code, I quickly edited the names. This works but I have JPA mapping with fetch type as "LAZY". After using the above code it giving me error as "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:", think I need to make it EAGER.

Comment: That would be "ask a new question".  Because this Q&A is about plain Java streams, not JPA, etc.  (And the problem sounds like it is orthogonal to this one.)